# Hiding Username and Password in URL of Forms 11g

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I have a main page that the user needs to input the username and password.
Upon logging-in, some forms that are being called by the main page shows the username and password in the URL. How can I remove it?
Im using the WEB.SHOW_DOCUMENT for the URL.

Answer (score 1):

Do not include the userid parameter in the URL.  The user will be prompted to log in.  Alternatively, enable SSO.  If you are calling a form from a form use OPEN_FORM, CALL_FORM, or NEW_FORM rather than WEB.SHOW.  WEB.SHOW_DOCUMENT is intended to call web content like web pages and not other forms, although technically possible with limitations.